# React When i am trying to get into a nested object the fetch throws me an undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, javascript-objects

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'



function PokemonCard() {
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(setPokemon)
},[])
const pokemonType = pokemon.types
console.log(pokemonType)

//HERE I GET THE ERROR
pokemonType.map(x => console.log(x.type.name))
return (
<div>
    <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
      {/* <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default}></img> */}
      {/* <h2>Type: {pokemonType}</h2> */}
      <h2>Height: {pokemon.height}</h2>
      <h2>Weight: {pokemon.weight}</h2>
</div>
)
}


export default PokemonCard;
```

this is the link for the api

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard

when i try to get into the pokemon.types.type.name i get a error saying
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at PokemonCard (PokemonCard.js:16:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to `pokemonType` is undefined initially. Try using [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
pokemonType?.map((x) => console.log(x.type.name));
```

Answer for what you tried in the comment:

```
const pokemonType = pokemon.types?.[0]?.type.name;
```

If you wanted to get the types rendered then use this:

```js
function PokemonCard() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setPokemon);
  }, []);

  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
      {pokemon.types &&
        pokemon.types.map(({ type: { name } }) => (
          <p key={name}>{capitalizeFirstLetter(name)}</p>
        ))}
      <h2>Height: {pokemon.height}</h2>
      <h2>Weight: {pokemon.weight}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<PokemonCard />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: const pokemonType = pokemon?.types[0].type.name

Comment: just put that in getting same error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at PokemonCard (PokemonCard.js:13:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)

Comment: const pokemonType = pokemon.types
    const typeName = pokemonType?.map(x => console.log(x.type.name))
    
    console.log(typeName)

Comment: @allenmor, check the answer !

Comment: const nameCapital = pokemonName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemonName.slice(1);

Comment: now im trying to make the name capital and its throwing me an error

Comment: PokemonCard.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')
    at PokemonCard (PokemonCard.js:18:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.j

Comment: sorry didnt know how to do that smh

Answer (score 0):

`map` over the types property in the JSX. Note that the objects in the types array doesn't hold `height` or `weight` properties so I'm assuming you wanted to add the `height` and `weight` from the pokemon object.

If you want to make the name uppercase add a class to the element that holds the name, and use CSS to make it uppercase. If you meant only to capitalise the first letter use `.pokemonName { text-transform: capitalize; }` instead.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function PokemonCard() {

  const [ pokemon, setPokemon ] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setPokemon);
  }, [])

  if (!pokemon) return <div>Loading pokemon data</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {pokemon.types.map(({ id, type }) => {
        return (
          <div key={id}>
            <h3 className="pokemonName">
              {type.name}
            </h3>
            <p>Height: {pokemon.height}</p>
            <p>Weight: {pokemon.weight}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PokemonCard />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.pokemonName { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```